# Can't run azure function on cloud

Tags: python, azure, deployment, azure-functions, cloud

I created two azure functions. One that is called via an http request and leaves a message in the storage account queue and another that is triggered when a message arrives in that queue. Both functions work fine locally and perform the processes correctly. However, when I deploy and test in the cloud the functions I am getting the following error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6KWq.png)

It is important to mention that this library is in the requirements and I have already checked the environment that is created when I deploy and in it I find all the libraries installed. The functions were implemented in python 3.8.12.

Comment: The error says that validators module is not available. Can you please add the full error message?

Comment: Please add the full log trace of the error message

Comment: @NagaBudigam I updated the image in the question.

Comment: @Daniela I was also facing the same issue, and in my case, I changed the function app version for python to a lower one like 3.8 to 3.7. I wasted my 2-3 days on it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validators' ......

The Exception shows that the required Module was not able to be found in by the Azure Function. Refer [Troubleshoot modulenotfounderror](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#troubleshoot-modulenotfounderror)

To avoid this exception, you have to add the required **Module** in a **requirement.txt** file.

```json
// requirements.txt 
# ModuleName version
azure-functions=="xxxx"
validators == "XXX"
```

#### References:

- GitHub Fix [Link 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/20427#issuecomment-1133510309) & [Link 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/477#issuecomment-948290439)